# VB TCP Server with multiple clients

Tags: vb.net

I have a simple TCP server and client working but can only communicate from client to server, i would like to know how to forward all incoming messages to all clients, when the client connects they would have to be stored, not sure how to do this, thanks in advance.
The code does not use Winsock control!
The examples are on the microsoft website, [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Store the clients in a collection as they connect, then loop thru the collection to send data.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a list of Sockets in your application.  Whenever a client connects add it to this list, and remove it when it disconnects.  Whenever you receive a message just loop through this list and resend the message to each client, optionally ignoring the client that originally sent the message.  I really can't get more specific without knowing exactly where you intend to take the design.